# Good matches less than 10, images not gets stitched

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-stitching

I am stitching multiple images to get orthomosaic as a result. I am using SURF, BF matcher. Part of stiching code which detects ands matches is as below:

```
detector = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create(400)
gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(image1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret1, mask1 = cv2.threshold(gray1,1,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
kp1, descriptors1 = detector.detectAndCompute(gray1,mask1)

gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(image2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret2, mask2 = cv2.threshold(gray2,1,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
kp2, descriptors2 = detector.detectAndCompute(gray2,mask2)

keypoints1Im = cv2.drawKeypoints(image1, kp1, outImage = cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DEFAULT, color=(0,0,255))
# util.display("KEYPOINTS",keypoints1Im)
keypoints2Im = cv2.drawKeypoints(image2, kp2, outImage = cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DEFAULT, color=(0,0,255))
# util.display("KEYPOINTS",keypoints2Im)

matcher = cv2.BFMatcher()
matches = matcher.knnMatch(descriptors2,descriptors1, k=2)

good = []
for m, n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.55 * n.distance:
        good.append(m)

print (str(len(good)) + " Matches were Found")

if len(good) <= 10:
    return image1

matches = copy.copy(good)

matchDrawing = util.drawMatches(gray2,kp2,gray1,kp1,matches)
```

At some point I am getting matches 4 or less than that. According to code its returning image.

```
if len(good) <= 10:
    return image1
```

So images are not getting stitched for that duration and result is not as expected.

After this code, there is homography calculation and wraping of images which stitches images. Above I am focusing only on issue part.

Any idea what else we can do if matches are less than 10 to get images stitched?

Answer (score 0):

This code simply draw matching keypoints in the images, it does not stich the images, and 10 good matches are a really small value, that's why if the good matches are less than 10, the images are considered non-matching and the first image is returned. One thing you can do is to increase the fraction of the distance to consider a match a good match, for example in many example in the web you can see that usually 0.75 is used. Try to modify this value and see what happens. You can also remove the part where you check if good matches are more than 10 and take a look at the `matchDrawing` to see if what is matched is right.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I removed that condition `if len(good) <= 10`, It gives me error at time of stitching/wraping process `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2260,7630,3) (1634,1423)`